OLS - relationship between singular values and confidence intervals
I've recently read that small singular values (in the context of SVD) of the data matrix lead to unreliable (noisy) estimates of the $\beta$ coefficients in OLS. Is there some formula that relates this to the confidence intervals or standard errors of the estimates? In other words, relationship between the (smallest) singular values of the data matrix, vs the uncertainty about the betas?

It's not that simple.  For a thorough analysis read Belsley, Kuh, & Welsch's book on Regression Diagnostic.
